# Snow by date php

Tags: php

I have a script to show snow on the website 
I have just to add this code that calls a js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="snowstorm.js"></script>
```

Now I would to have this line to work every year from 15 December and stops at 15 January

Example :

```
If date >15 December && < 15 January  { echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="snowstorm.js" ></script>'}
```

Any help please?

Best regards

Comment: please paste snowstorm.js code

Comment: Hello Shankar the cose is too long and it can not be pasted here I give you a link to download it (I found it here ): http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/bg/snowstorm.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects:

```
$now = new DateTime();
if ($now >= new DateTime('December 15') || $now <= new DateTime('January 15')) {
    echo '<script src="snowstorm.js"></script>';
}
```

I'm using **logical or** `||` here because the script should be shown if the date is before January 15 of this year **or** if the date is after December 15 of this year.

The condition becomes slightly more complicated with **logical and** as you would have to account for the different years.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$date = time(); //current time. output timestamp format

date('n')==1?$currentYear=date('Y')-1:$currentYear=date('Y');

if($date > mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 15, $currentYear) && $date < mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 15,$currentYear+1))
{
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="snowstorm.js" ></script>';
}
```

about php [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Comment: Hello Thank you 
I would like to have that every year and not only 2014 and 2015 
Will it be possible please?

Comment: @Cattla echo will print line on web page,It will not call expression dynamically

Comment: Hello sorry to come back 
It stopped when 2015 came :( :( :( any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Using $.getScript(): we can call script plugin based on condition dynamically.

```
$.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js");
```

or else you can append script like this

```
$('head').append($('<script>').attr('type', 'text/javascript').attr('src', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'));
```

To set date condition please refer this [Link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/08/jquery-check-given-date-greater-than.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add the following code at the top of your `index.html` / `index.php` file:

```
if(date("m.d") >= "12.15" && date("m.d") <= "01.15"){  // check the date
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="snowstorm.js" ></script>';  // add the script if within the date range
}
```

*Readup:* [`date` | PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)